# How to change the default code template for C++ in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, code-templates

I'm using Eclipse as an IDE for C++ programming. When creating a new project, I get the following default template:

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : .cpp
// Author      : "name I can specify"
// Version     :
// Copyright   : ©opyRights
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "" << endl; // prints 
return 0;
}
```

So, what I want to know is: How can I change this default template as a whole - the include files, the first part which contains the Name (in blank), and other information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are located in the preferences window. Here is the path:

Window > Preferences > C++ > Editor > Templates > Edit

A 'New Template' window should appear.

Comment: I've made a new template, however when I make a new project I'm still finding the mentioned above template, the new template doesn't appear automatically as default.

Comment: Ok, however the Asked question is still non-answered.

Comment: @YoussofKamalEl-Din I edited the answer. Does it work?

Comment: It helps a little. Thought, it's about templates while coding. But I mean the Default c++ source file, when I edit it, I don't find any changes when creating a new project. Hope you understood.

Comment: @youssof That's weird.

Comment: If you can make a video-or pictures-, explaining how to change the default c++ source file, so that on creating new project find the modified settings. Thanks for following anyway :)

Comment: @youssof I don't give up very easily, so I tried one more thing. Have a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqm4CB1BX6Y Might get you one step closer, anyway. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The template is probably stored in a jar file inside the Eclipse's plugin folder. You can use WinRAR to search within all the jar files. Search for a significant word, like `Author      :`. Once found the jar file, unzip it, modify the template, re-zip it, rename it to jar. Go back to the Eclipse's plugin folder, make a backup of the old jar (rar it or 7zip it or move it from that folder) and replace it with your new jar (it must have the exact same filename).

Comment: This was helpful. But it isn't simple as compressing and renaming it; such method had lead to a corrupted jar file. Rather it's better to use this command format " jar cf jar-file input-file(s) ", which is mentioned here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html but this lead to some bug and 'Hello world C++ Project' selection was gone. safest was to change it in-place (open jar file containing the template with WinRAR, open .cpp template with editor, change it and apply changes to this jar.) But hadn't shown any changes, everything is as it is. Thanks anyway : )

Answer (score 0):

You'll fine it here: Windows -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Code Templates

[image]